# HTML Resize font based on screen

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I created the following `div`:

```css
#orderHistory {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#orderHistoryContent {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: grid;
    font-size: 14px;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
}

#orderHistoryContent div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.order-history-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}
#orderHistoryContent label {
  font-size: 1vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #orderHistoryContent {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="orderHistory">
                <label class="title">Order history</label>
                <div id="orderHistoryContent">
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Action</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Market</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Coin</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>DateTimeEntered</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Quantity</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Amount</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Target price</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Limit price</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Price</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>DateTimeExecuted</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Status</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="order-history-header">
                        <label>Profit</label>
                    </div>
                <div style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);">             <label>Buy</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">             <label>USDT</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(220, 255, 193);">             <label>BTC</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">             <label>2021-05-08 00:00:00</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">             <label>999999.00000000</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">             <label>0.00</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">             <label>0.000000</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">             <label>0.000000</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);">             <label>56723.640000</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);">             <label></label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(137, 186, 255);">             <label>New</label>         </div>         <div style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);">             <label></label>         </div></div>
            </div>
```

But the font size doesn't change when I am on a smaller screen (1080 x 2400 pixels) using the `@media` query.

Here is the result on my phone (OnePlus 8T) with the above snippet:
[image]

How can I change the font size based on screen width?

Comment: Have you set the viewport? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: No I haven't, but when I do that, my entire webpage is messed up on my phone. Everything is way smaller. Like, divs that are set to 100% are not 100% anymore, but like 40%???

Comment: You got a specificity problem as well. `#orderHistoryContent label` have higher specificity than `#orderHistoryContent`. A quick fix is to write `font-size: 12px !important;`.

Comment: Does that need to change anything? Nothing changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vw` units to change the font size. Try this in your code

```css
#orderHistory {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#orderHistoryContent {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: grid;
    font-size: 14px;
    grid-template-columns: min-content auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
}

#orderHistoryContent div {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.order-history-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1vw;
}
label {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1D0F73;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="orderHistory">
  <label class="title">Order history</label>
  <div id="orderHistoryContent">
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Action</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Market</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Coin</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>DateTimeEntered</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Quantity</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Amount</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Target price</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Limit price</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Price</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>DateTimeExecuted</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Status</label>
    </div>
    <div class="order-history-header">
      <label>Profit</label>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);"> <label>Buy</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> <label>USDT</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(220, 255, 193);"> <label>BTC</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);"> <label>2021-05-08 00:00:00</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);"> <label>999999.00000000</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);"> <label>0.00</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);"> <label>0.000000</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);"> <label>0.000000</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 227, 214);"> <label>56723.640000</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(251, 255, 191);"> <label></label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(137, 186, 255);"> <label>New</label> </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(251, 216, 255);"> <label></label> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem I am starting to get with `em`, `rem` and `vw` is that on a certain moment, the browser has the correct font size, but my mobile is still too large. When my mobile is correct, the browser on my pc is way too small. How can I change them seperate from each other?

Comment: That's why you may need to use `@media` queries. The code above however makes the font fit the box size. You'll notice when you go to full screen the font fills the box and mobile it also shrinks to fill the boxes. Not sure what else you want.

Comment: I updated my snippet with the problem described below the snippet. I also added a new result image from my phone!

Comment: I don't know what to say. I've checked it on 3 devices and resized my browser window and the font re-sizes to the size of its box and none of the font overflows into another. Even the code snippet above is sized correctly in both fullscreen and the preview views.

Comment: Have you checked my snippet on 3 devices or your own snippet? The size does get changed using the `vw`, but it doesn't set it to `12px` or I even tried `6px`.

Comment: I have pasted your code into this Codepen and it works fine. https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/vYxOGgp?editors=1100 No matter what size I make the window it shrinks and grows nicely. I also saved an index.html on the desktop and opened it in my both EDGE and FIREFOX and no issues.

Comment: But does the `@media` thing do anything with your devices? I have set the font size to `6px`, but I can't see any font jump at a certain point?

Comment: Because you’ve already added the `vw` above you don’t need the `@media`. Delete the `vw` font and see what happens. Then add them back and delete the `@media`

Comment: Ah, I can see. when using `@media` I need to set my font to 3px to not overlap fields with each other. On firefox the `vw` does work on both pc and mobile. But Chrome on mobile is the problem here. Tried to clear cache and browser history, but both didn't work. Could it be a limit of the `vw`, that it can't go smaller? Changing the `font-size: 0.75vw;` to a lower value does change the font on my phone to a smaller one? But then my pc font is too small

Answer (score 1):

Use `em` or `rem` for font units so they scale appropriately on different screen sizes.

More information: https://css-tricks.com/confused-rem-em/

Comment: What needs to be `em` or `rem`? The font size?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Honestly, if you want a responsive page, use that for everything. Font, spaces, etc. Then you only need to set the font on the body and everything will adapt to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this inside your #orderHistoryContent and .title, feel free to mess with this
The first one says if the width of the screen is 320px, and it's portrait (referring to holding phone normally in vertical position), then change font-size to 10 pixels, then if the minimum width 960px which is like computer screen orientation landscape, change font-size 14 pixels. It's like if/else conditioning but in css based on size of screens. You can test this on your browser using developer tools or lookup more resources online such as this:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```
    @media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 320px) {
        font-size:10px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 960px) {
        font-size:14px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize elements based on screen width using media queries.

Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .element {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

This would set your font-size to 12px if your current max width is less than or equal to 800px.